# JavaScript: поиск числа вхождений символов в строку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Есть ли способ посчитать количество определенных символов в строке?

*Например*: сколько вхождений символов 'a', '?', '<' в стоку "Hello, are you here??".

Сам пока допер только с регулярными выражениями, работает, (правильно? или есть другой способ?):

```
var my_text = document.getElementById('myTextArea');
var result = my_text.value.match(/[a\?\<]/g).length;
```

Все обрабатывается по **onkeyup** при печатании, приму любые ваши комментарии.

Comment: А циклом не проще будет? Написать функцию и прогонять через неё строку.

Comment: а чем вас таки не устраивает `my_text.value.match(/[a\?\<]/g).length;` ?
все другие способы будут извратными, например: 

    my_text.split('').filter(function(a){return ['a','?','<'].indexOf(a)>-1;}).length

Comment: вот посмотрите бенчмарки решений http://jsperf.com/split-vs-regexp-in-search-entries

Comment: на хроме вот так быстрее всего: 

my_text.match(/a|\<|\?/g).length

Comment: @eicto Ваш вариант принципиально не может быть быстрее. Он может быть только медленнее ввиду устройства работы регулярных выражений.

Comment: @ReinRaus я привел бенчмарки, и указал что быстрее регекспов ничего не работает.

Comment: @eicto, просто увидев в бенчмарке, что  

   my_text.match(/a|\<|\?/g).length
отрабатывает быстрее, чем  

   my_text.match([a<?]/g).length
сразу становится понятно, что бенчмарк измеряет скорость неправильно.  
Потому что в лучшем случае `a|<|\?` будет оптимизировано до [a<?], а в худшем останется без оптимизации и будет работать медленнее.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
("Hello, are you here??".split("a").length - 1);
```

Comment: > сколько вхождений символов {'a', '?', '<'} в стоку "Hello, are you here??"

Comment: `"Hello, are you here??".split(/[a\?\<]/)`

Comment: Как все сложно. match возвращает массив, если регулярное выражение с модификатором g, осталось только найти длину массива.